# String Replace not working properly

Tags: c#, string

This is my method that is supposed to return a parsed document.

```
public string GetParsedDocument(string Document)
{
   Document.Replace("{{tag}}", ParseMarkup(Tag.Text));
   return Document
}
```

Basically I parse the document and write it to a file like this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(SaveDialog.FileName, GetParsedDocument(TestProgram.Properties.Resources.Document));
```

Yet when I open the file, non of my changes are there. What's going on? I've tried making the strings verbatim and I've tested to see if it's any of the other components that aren't working; but it isn't. String replace is not working. Or it's not returning properly. Any ideas?

Comment: please, don't use capital letter as first char for the variables!

Comment: Did you read the documentation for String.Replace before suspecting a bug in this very-commonly-used method? (In particular, the highlighed note: "This method does not modify the value of the current instance. Instead, it returns a new string in which all occurrences of oldValue are replaced by newValue.")

Comment: @JonSkeet Not really needed, IntelliSense will tell you already. You can judge by the return value type.

Comment: @NaNNy - While I completely agree with you, there is no right or wrong way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so all its methods return the new string as a result. You should go like this:

```
string parsedDocument = Document.Replace("{{tag}}", ParseMarkup(Tag.Text));
return parsedDocument;
```

Answer (score 4):

`Replace` does not work inplace, but is a function that RETURNS the changed string

```
return Document.Replace("{{tag}}", ParseMarkup(Tag.Text));
```

Now you are getting the changed version.